# Amount including fee

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript and two input boxes.One of the input box is **readonly** and is automatically update depending upon the value of the other textbox.

Input Boxes

```
<input type="text" name="amount" class="validate[required] text-input" id="amount">
<input type="text" name="fee" readonly id="fee">
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount'), //get the amount BTC to be sold 
    var fee = document.getElementById('fee');
    var percentage = 1;
    amount.onkeyup = function () {
        var result = parseFloat(amount.value) * 0.01;
        var finalResult = result + parseFloat(amount.value);
        fee.value = !isNaN(finalresult) ? finalresult : '';
    };
}
</script>
```

For some reason, the code doesn't seem to be taking any effect when a value is typed in the **amount** box.
What may be the reason?

Comment: It recommended me and I just hit it!

Comment: You have a syntax error. Change `var fee` to just `fee`, or change the comma on the line preceding it to a semicolon.

Comment: Also, JavaScript is case-sensitive. Fix `!isNaN(finalresult) ? finalresult : '';` to be `!isNaN(finalResult) ? finalResult : '';`

Comment: @Blazemonger Why? `fee` shouldn't be in the global scope as far as I can see

Comment: When you fix the typos that Blazemonger and I suggest, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/U9ZvD/

Comment: @Bojangles Because of the comma on the preceding line. `var` can only be used at the start of a new line.

Comment: @j08691 & Blazemonger,
Thanks..works awesome now.

Comment: @Blazemonger Ah yes, missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your fixed code on JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PC7Qv/

```
window.onload = function(){
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
    var fee = document.getElementById('fee');

    var percentage = 1;

    amount.onkeyup = function () {
        var result = parseFloat(amount.value) * 0.01;
        var finalResult = result + parseFloat(amount.value);
        fee.value = !isNaN(finalResult) ? finalResult : '';
    }
}
```

Looks as though you had a couple of errors, one was the comma on line 2 and the other you missed off the capital in `finalResult` when setting `fee.value`

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/LSWyr/
 Sorry, looks like I am too late.

```
 window.onload = function () {
  var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
  var fee = document.getElementById('fee');
  var percentage = 1;
  amount.onkeyup = function () {
    var result = parseFloat(amount.value) * 0.01;
    var finalResult = result + parseFloat(amount.value);
    fee.value = !isNaN(finalResult) ? finalResult : '';
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you also man.But unfortunately, I can only mark 1 answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I came before him though :P I was late as compared to comments. :P